# How to detect time in Go?

Tags: time, go

I need to parse the  date_id field from emails headers. However these seem to have slightly different layouts so I've started to build a switch case/block . I'm wondering if that's really the way to fix this issue.

```
        case strings.Contains(h.Headers[bk].Date, "(CEST)"):
            layout = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)"
        case strings.Contains(h.Headers[bk].Date, "(EDT)"):
            layout = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)"
        default:
            layout = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`mail.Header`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#Header) and simply call [`.Date()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#Header.Date) on it.

Another option is to read the code starting from [line 70](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/mail/message.go?#L70) and write your own function.